# How to control which digit is generated from a GAN trained in MNIST?

Tags: python, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm interested in GAN so I followed this tutorial [link](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/generative-adversarial-networks?fbclid=IwAR1Mq1ePB74ttO6WSnNX4zRrYuUHDBJ39Gwaea5pwjO9x4K-gVPJEdQMLVA) about GANs for MNIST with Keras. The result was that it generated a 4x4 image with random digit like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yGm8.png). I want to ask how to generate 4x4 image with digit that I want and not random digits like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrtnc.png).

```
def plot_generated_images(epoch, generator, examples=16, dim=(4, 4), figsize=(4, 4)):
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[examples, random_dim])
    generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
    generated_images = generated_images.reshape(examples, 28, 28)

plt.figure(figsize=figsize)

for i in range(generated_images.shape[0]):
    plt.subplot(dim[0], dim[1], i+1)
    plt.imshow(generated_images[i], interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray_r')
    plt.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('gan_generated_image_epoch_%d.png' % epoch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to filter the training data, like

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

# Set specific target digit you want to generator
TARGET_DIGIT = 5

# Get data
(trainX, trainy), (testX, testy) = mnist.load_data()

# Filter it
trainX, trainy = trainX[trainy==TARGET_DIGIT], trainy[trainy==TARGET_DIGIT]
```

Then train the GAN model based on the filtered data and noise. Because the discriminator is only classifying it's fake or real, it should be fine if only use a specific digit label to train.

By repeating it 10 times for each digit, you can generate what number you want.
But remember the training data size reduced, the epochs needs increasing at the same time.

I have tried to set the target digit to 5 by given the `epochs = 300` and `batch size = 128` with basic GAN architecture. This is the what generator plot when epoch=150: [image: digit 5, epoch 150]; and epoch=300:[image: digit 5, epoch 300]

Answer (score 0):

The type of GAN you used doesn't have any way of controlling which number it generates. For that you would need to train a [Conditional GAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1784).

The only means you have to *control* what images the GAN is generating is through the **noise vector** you input to the generator. What you could try is to change the the values of this vector until you get the digit you want.

The easiest way to do so would be through a random seed

```py
np.random.seed(13)  # changing this number will result in different digits being created
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[examples, random_dim])
generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
generated_images = generated_images.reshape(examples, 28, 28)
```